# Javascript or php call to load/edit html table row data inside same page

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I’ve created an html table reading records from SQL trough PHP and managed to perform add, edit and delete actions.
Anyway my edit sciprt do it loading a blank page while I’d rather want to do it in the sama page.
Of course could try CRUD but that seems me over my knwoledge skills, so wuold like to use Java to pass them in a form already shown in the page (which I use to add new data).
I figured out at least two ways to do it:

- tag single html td contents and use java to read them in the form
- call back action from php and load them in the form

to avoid PHP/SQL call which may be slower, I’d prefer first option.
So created a table structure like that and tried to use variable $row['id_contact'] which match the unique ID from SQL table that way in the edit button:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTid_contact" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['id_contact'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTname" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTsurname" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['surname'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel1" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['tel1'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel2" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['tel2']. "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTmail" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['mail'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTorganization" . $row['id_contact'] . "'>" . $row['organization'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td> <button onclick='loadDATAtoCHANGE(" . $row['id_contact'] . ");'>edit</button></td>";
echo "<td> <a href=DELETEcontact/removeCONTACT.php?id=" . $row['id_contact'] . " \">&#9746;</a></td></td>";
echo "</tr>";


}
```

Despite my tries didn’t succeded in make Javascript recognize the row value.

Anyway was able to call **static data load - setting it for example equal to row 10 contents**, i.e.  value='"+document.getElementById('**rubricaCONTACTname10**').innerHTML+"'

```
function loadDATAtoCHANGE()
{
document.getElementById("rubricaCONTACTname").innerHTML = 
"<div class='tooltipLEFT'>&#x1F6C8;<span class='tooltiptext'>nome</span></div><input type='text' name='save1' id='enteringCONTACTname' placeholder='name' onkeyup='updateCONTACTname()' value='"+document.getElementById('rubricaCONTACTname10').innerHTML+"' /></br>";
}
```

As a matter of fact still hasn’t understood how to pass  $row['id_contact'] inside the very java call argument in order to make it dinamically choose the rows.
Basically I thought it should be simply placed inside the function argument () but, if so, my syntax didn’t work out.
Does some one has some suggestions to make it happen?

Should you find any other solutions would anyway give it chance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your onclick statement to:

```
echo "<td> <button onclick='loadDATAtoCHANGE(\'" . $row['id_contact'] . "\')'>
```

Because if you miss quotes around PHP var, JavaScript read the value like var and not like string.

In the function you have to use

```
function loadDATAtoCHANGE(id) {
    let dataToChange = "rubricaCONTACTname"+id;
    document.getElementById(dataToChange).innerHTML = 
    "<div class='tooltipLEFT'>&#x1F6C8;<span class='tooltiptext'>nome</span></div><input type='text' name='save1' id='enteringCONTACTname' placeholder='name' onkeyup='updateCONTACTname(id)' value='"+document.getElementById(dataToChange).innerHTML+"' /></br>";
}
```

Comment: you do mean in the php generating table? adding \' and close '\

Comment: sorry, wrong input entering without finishing t owrite, but on the java call side should I add something? how it should pass the row id instead of number 10 in this sentence? document.getElementById('rubricaCONTACTname10').innerHTML

Comment: I've edited my answer with the code for function to set dinamically data in Tooltip div. I added the id to  updateCONTACTname(id) call too, so you can update only the contact with modified data.

Comment: I'm wondering if you want to modify only contact name of all data (tel, email, ecc) for every contact. If so, I suggest to you to use a form with inputs and no a table filled with data.

Comment: all of the field. 
But, what am really unable to do is to pass the id.

Am ending up using this work around in the PHP: 
echo "<td> <button id='" . $row['id_contact'] . "' onclick=loadDATAtoCHANGE(this.id)>edit</button></td>";

while in the javascript:
function loadDATAtoCHANGE(ROW){
var element1= ROW;
..."+document.getElementById('rubricaCONTACTnameelement1').innerHTML+" .....
}

but it still show nothing, while if I call only "element1" it works fine but, of course, is not what I need. It seems am very bad in syntax on concatenating this variable to the span id

Comment: Try to change document.getElementById('rubricaCONTACTnameelement1') in document.getElementById('rubricaCONTACTname'+element1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233104/discussion-between-stefino76-and-dancode).

Answer (score 1):

Other way will be passing `this` inside your function where `this` refer to current button which is click and then use `.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("span[id*=rubricaCONTACT]").forEach...` to loop through all span tags which is inside your tr and then inside loop append new inputs in some variable and then add them inside your `form` tag .

Changes you can make in your ***php code*** :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {
//you can give any name inside data-name..it will label and name="" for input
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTid_contact" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='id'>" . $row['id_contact'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTname" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='name'>" . $row['name'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTsurname" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='surname'>" . $row['surname'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel1" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='tel1'>" . $row['tel1'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel2" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='tel2' >" . $row['tel2']. "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTmail" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='email'>" . $row['mail'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td><span id='rubricaCONTACTorganization" . $row['id_contact'] . "' data-name='organization'>" . $row['organization'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td> <button onclick='loadDATAtoCHANGE(this);'>edit</button></td>";
echo "<td> <a href=DELETEcontact/removeCONTACT.php?id=" . $row['id_contact'] . " \">&#9746;</a></td></td>";
echo "</tr>";


}
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function loadDATAtoCHANGE(selector) {
  var htmls = "";
  //loop through spans...
  selector.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("span[id*=rubricaCONTACT]").forEach(function(el) {
    //append new inputs ...
    htmls += `<div class="form-group"><label>${el.getAttribute("data-name").toUpperCase()}</label><input type="text" name="${el.getAttribute("data-name")}" class="form-control" value="${el.textContent}"> </div>`
  })
  htmls += `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>`
  document.getElementById("forms").innerHTML = htmls //add them inside form..
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTid_contact1' data-name="id">1</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTname1' data-name="name">abc</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTsurname1' data-name="surname">xyz</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel11' data-name="tel1">kokok</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel21' data-name="tel2">1345</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTmail1' data-name="email">abc@gmail.com</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTorganization1' data-name="org">somthinsghjk</span></td>
    <td> <button onclick='loadDATAtoCHANGE(this);'>edit</button></td>
    <td> <a href="DELETEcontact/removeCONTACT.php?id=1">&#9746;</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTid_contact2' data-name="id">2</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTname2' data-name="name">abc2</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTsurname2' data-name="surname">xyz2</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel12' data-name="tel1">kokok</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTtel22' data-name="tel2">1345</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTmail2' data-name="email">abc@gmail2.com</span></td>
    <td><span id='rubricaCONTACTorganization2' data-name="org">somthinsghjk</span></td>
    <td> <button onclick='loadDATAtoCHANGE(this);'>edit</button></td>
    <td> <a href="DELETEcontact/removeCONTACT.php?id=1">&#9746;</a></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<form id="forms">
  <!--data will come here-->
</form>
```

Comment: ok, the snippet doesn't lies, it works ok, Just a question: what following link is really useful to? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: If you want to make your site responsive you can use bootstrap .In above code `form-control ,form-group` are all predefined classes .  Check  [this](https://getbootstrap.com/) for information .

Comment: nice, didn't knew about that. somehow am still CMS oriented and when forced to code is just for such small personal tools that mobile oriented project are completely out of my mind. anyway that's hitting the core idea I always had, all people developing app while cross html language is already there. stiil, what this script call is really useful in this case? didn't saw specific call at that (is just for CSS?)